# Help on step solving $\int \frac{1}{1+\sin(x)} dx$

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble finding the solution to the following integral

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\sin(x)} dx$$

I know that the first step should be:

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\sin(x)} dx= \int \frac{1-\sin(x)}{(1+\sin(x))(1-\sin(x))} dx$$

But I'm not sure what steps I should take afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this problem before. After the suggestion of zz20s, your integral is

$$\int\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^2x}dx$$

Next step is to simplify

$$\int \sec^2(x)-\sec(x) \tan(x)dx$$

which is then

$$\int \sec^2(x)dx -\int \sec(x) \tan(x)dx$$

Then the answer is

$$\tan(x)-\sec(x) + C$$

Answer (score 1):

You're doing great so far!

Note that $(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)=1- \sin^2 x=\cos^2 x$.

Now, split the integrand into $\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}- \frac{\sin x}{cos^2 x}$. Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\dfrac1{1+\sin x}=\dfrac1{1+\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2-x\right)}=\dfrac{\sec^2\left(\dfrac\pi4-\dfrac x2\right)}2$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Set $t=\tan\dfrac x2$

$$\dfrac1{1+\sin x}=\dfrac{\sec^2\dfrac x2}{\left(1+\tan\dfrac x2\right)^2}$$